# How to get supernavigationcontroller

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigationcontroller with a subnavigationcontroller as you can see in the picture. now my question here is how can I get the supernavigationcontroller of the navigationcontroller?

when you press on a cell in de subnavigationcontroller, I want to add a viewcontroller to the superviewcontroller.

http://cl.ly/image/060u1D2f3S2x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using property `parentViewController`. It should return what you need

Comment: Thanks!! it worked indeed using (self.navigationController.parentViewController.navigationController)